# IE ignoring class="" problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a complex web page (JavaScript application) where an included style sheet contains the following rule:

```
.floatleft {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Within that complex layout there is a `DIV` element:

```
<div class="floatleft" width="25%">
```

My problem is that IE9 (**quirks mode**) is ignoring the `floatleft` class. In fact, [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) says: `This element has no style rules.`.

Other rules on the page work fine and FireFox, Chrome show the correct layout.

Some more insights:

- This is not related to `float:left` since a `border:1px solid red` doesn't show up either.
- The DIV parent's parent has also another `class` attribute that works.
- A nested child of the problematic DIV also has a working `class` attribute.
- An inline `style="float:left"` works.
- removing the `width` attribute doesn't help
- full CSS code is available here: http://pastebin.com/1JAATMZD

Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem in a simplified test case (in fact the same rule works fine in another application) and I can't give you an URL to see the problem since it's an application with restricted access.

I'd be happy anyway if someone could give me some more hint how to spot the problem. AFAIK Internet Explorer is known to mess up with style rules sometimes.

Comment: Do divs have a width-attribute? I think it should be `style="width:25%;"`

Comment: **Quirks mode**? No wonder you're experiecing problems with IE, when you're actually using IE5. Add `<!doctype html>` to the beginning of your markup.

Comment: What is in your css immediately before this rule? It could be that it is interfering with it in some way, e.g. if the immediately preceding text was being interpreted as part of the selector.

Comment: It should accept the style, other wise could you please send as a link what you have done so that we recognize the problem.

Comment: +1 The width attribute does not appear in the set of allowed attributes for HTML4.

Comment: Removing `width` doesn't help. The full CSS code is at http://pastebin.com/1JAATMZD where you can see the preceding CSS rule is a class definition. Exiting quirks mode would require to rewrite the whole application (300klines+ of code).

Comment: By the way, "floatleft", "greytext" and "bold" are horrible names for CSS classes. What if you wanted all your text that is currently grey to instead be red? Would you change it to `.greytext { color: red; }`? You may as well use a style attribute if you want to do that. CSS class names should describe their *content* not their *style*

Comment: doctype is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`

Comment: Gareth, you're right but that doesn't help me. I'm not the one that choose the name, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced the same problem today in IE7.

I have a <div> element created in Javascript. I wanted to style it using a CSS class, but I found that IE7 didn't apply the style for my <div>.

(If I'll create the <div> directly in HTML without Javascript, IE7 will apply correctly the CSS class on my element).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>::</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .childDiv{background:red;padding:10px;color:yellow;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
      parentDiv.setAttribute("id", "parentDiv");

      var childDiv = document.createElement("div");
      childDiv.setAttribute("class", "childDiv");
      childDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello IE7!"));

      parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);
      document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I actually found that **setAttribute() works very buggy in IE7** when it is used to set the class name of an Element.

The real solution for my code is to use className property instead of setAttribute().

```
childDiv.className = "childDiv";
```

<strike>The solution I found so far is to use an ID attribute instead of Class:</strike>

```
#childDiv{background:red;padding:10px;color:yellow;}
```

and

```
childDiv.setAttribute("id", "childDiv");
```

or to refer my <div> using the parent's ID:

```
#parentDiv div{background:red;padding:10px;color:yellow;}
```